# I need some component selection help with a nixie tube AVR speedometer

Tags: avr, atmega, nixie

I know enough to be dangerous, i can build circuits and make minor changes but i am not an expert.  I put this together after looking at schematics i have found online and i need some help getting the right components.  The individual components i cant take credit for but i think the idea and final unit will be unique.

This is a speedometer for my 1950 Studebaker.  It is a modern charging/ battery system.  Should give between 11 and 14 volts.  Both power supplies i have, the avr i am familiar with and have, i used it to control a skeeball machine.  It uses a pulse generator on the transmission (new Dakota digital sen-01-1), i then modified the self powered sine to square wave circuit to run off of available power.  I am hoping this will make it more sensitive.  I am using the Russian equivalent to the Nixie drivers 74141.

1: i would like to control 2 of the elements without the need for a chip what should i do here? (mpsa42 and a 33k resistor? I have!)

2: Between the at mega avr and the 74141 (K155ID1)? do i need anything?

3: Do i need to do something special on the input voltage for these 74141 s?

4 and 5: I would also like to use ne2 lamps to replace my hi beam and left and right turn indicators.  These are roughly a 12v signal i have 5v and 170v what circuit should i use?  Hi beam may be on for long times.  (tip 102?)

6: (not numbered on schematic) Is my use of the sine to square appropriate.

MY hand drawn schematic: http://i871.photobucket.com/albums/ab280/FortyTwo-edo/nispedov1.jpg

Sorry this is long but i have been looking at this for awhile and finally need to get it prototyped before snow so i can test it before i build the case.

Thanks
Ed Owens

Comment: sine to square: http://www.redcircuits.com/Page17.htm

Comment: good Nixie data: http://www.tube-tester.com/sites/nixie/74141-NDT/74141-NDT.htm

Comment: Just got sending unit hooked up at 70 ish i was turning 180 hurtz and about 4.2 v ac.  I figure this should be able to handle at least 6 volts whitch i should never exceed.

Answer (score 1):

1) I used MPSA42 transistors as low side switches in my Nixie tube clock. A 10K current limit resistor on the anode of the tube and (as I recall - schematics not at hand) a 68K resistor on the base of the transistor. The MPSA42 components are cheap enough that you can experiment with them.

Comment: My transisters are extras left over from my nixie clock.  IT had a 33k resister on the signal wire and thats it.  Thanks

Comment: @Ed Owens did you make hack-a-day or something like that for your nixie clock? Or did you just copy their idea?